# Question about the proof of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem 1

Tags: real-analysis

In Folland's textbook:

The proof of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem 1.
For all $f\in \mathcal{F}$ which is equicontinuous. By pointwise boundedness, $\{f(x_j): f\in\mathcal{F}\}$ is bounded. There is a finite set $\{z_1, \dots, z_k\}\subset \mathbb{C}$ that is $\epsilon/4 $-dense. Let $A=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$, $B=\{z_1, \dots, z_m\}$. For each $\phi\in B^A$, let
$$\mathcal{F}_{\phi}=\{f\in\mathcal{F}: \mid f(x_j)-\phi(x_j)\mid<\frac{1}{4} \epsilon\}$$
... It shows that $\mid f(x)-g(x)\mid<\epsilon$ for all $x$ and $f\in \mathcal{F}$.

> Q1: What does "$1/4 \epsilon$-dense" mean?

Is the for each $f(x_j)$, we have $\mid f(x_j)-z_k\mid<\epsilon/4$? But in this way, why for each $\phi\in B^A$ we have $$\mid f(x_j)-\phi(x_j)\mid<\frac{1}{4} \epsilon?$$
That is $\phi(x_j)=z_k$?

> Q2: Why the set $B^A$ of functions from A to B is finite?
>
> Q3: Why $\cup_{\phi}\mathcal{F}_{\phi}=\mathcal{F}$?

Clearly, $\mathcal{F}\subset \cup_{\phi}\mathcal{F}_{\phi}$

> Q4: Where does prove $\mathcal{F}$ is totally bounded in the uniform metric?

Its metric $\mid  \mid $ is uniform metric in all of the proof?

Comment: I think $1/4\epsilon$-dense should be $\epsilon/4$-dense.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\epsilon$-dense means every point of your set is within a distance $\epsilon$ of some $z_i$.

$B^A$ is finite, since $A$ and $B$ are.

You say it is clear that $\cal F\subset\bigcup_\phi\cal F_\phi$. As
$\cal F_\phi\subseteq\cal F$ by definition, then it's clear that
$\bigcup_\phi\cal F_\phi\subseteq\cal F$.

I don't have enough information to answer your Q4.

Comment: In its proof, it just uses the absolute value(metric) but not the uniform metric. So why it could get $\mathcal{F}$ is totally bounded in the uniform metric?

Comment: It shows that $\mid f(x)-g(x)\mid<\epsilon$ for all $x$ and $f\in \mathcal{F}$.